# Как задать max-width для background-image?

Tags: html, css

Фоновые картинки в `div` подгружаются динамически

Как сжать фоновое изображение если оно больше родительского объекта, но не растягивать его если меньше?

```
div {
  background: url('/img.png') no-repeat center center;
  background-size: contain;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

P.S.: `background-size: contain;` растягивает маленькие изображения, а этого требуется избежать.

Comment: По-моему можно сделать размер родительского блока по содержимому. Вот только тег не помню.

Answer (score 4):

Чистым CSS это не делается.

Если вы говорите, что изображения подгружаются динамически, значит, есть какой-то javascript, который это делает. Так, после загрузки изображения, можно проверить его размер, сопоставить с размером блока, и поменять `background-size`. При этом, если размер блока может меняться со временем, имеет смысл пересчитывать `background-size` при изменении размеров (как правило, достаточно подписаться на событие `window.resize`).

Впрочем, если таких блоков много, вышеописанный подход будет вызывать лаги. Кроме того, в некоторых браузерах для `background-image` не поддерживается anti aliasing, что приводит к заметному ухудшению качества картинки при масштабировании.

Возможно, вам стоит использовать `<canvas>` или `<svg>` вместо того, чтобы динамически менять фон?

Так же можно придумать такую конструкцию: основному `<div>` не задавать фон. Вместо этого поместить внутрь еще один `<div>` или `<img>` с абсолютным позиционированием и `max-width`, и задать фон ему. Тут, правда, начнутся проблемы с вертикальным выравниванием, да и вообще это не очень хорошее решение: html код потеряет в читаемости. Впрочем, работать будет быстрее, чем подписка на события, так как меньше программных манипуляций с DOM.

Answer (score 1):

В `background-size` можно использовать `calc`.

```
.bg
{
    background-size: calc(min(500px, 100%));
}
```

Надо заметить, что `calc` можно использовать и по одной, и по обеим сторонам. 
Тоже-самое работает для свойства `background-position`

Comment: Храни вас гасподь! :) сто раз слышал про мин, и пропускал мимо ушей.